# How to open a prettyPhoto lightbox automatically when the page loads?

Tags: jquery, autoload

I am really new to Jquery and I have found several examples of opening a light box using cookies and the the onload feature.  I am using the cookie example which works with fancybox, but I have been using prettyPhoto on all my sites and really do not want to change to fancybox.  I have tried a dozen different ways to get this to work but I have no luck.  Here is my code.  Any help or suggestions would be great.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
// !!! SEE THIS PLEASE !!!
// delete this line to make the modal box load only ONCE
// if you let it set to 'false' it will show every time .. set it to 'true' and it will never show
$.cookie("modal", 'false')

/**
  *  MODAL BOX
  */
// if the requested cookie does not have the value I am looking for show the modal box
if($.cookie("modal") != 'true')
{
    alert("sometext");
```

var where = "http://images.motortrend.com/photo_gallery/112_0611_39z+2006_bugatti_veyron+interior.jpg";
  var title = "";
  var comment = "";

function showLbox(){
   $.prettyPhoto.open(where, title, comment);
  }
        // on page load show the modal box
        // more info about the options you can find on the fancybox site

```
    // in the message is a link with the id "modal_close"
    // when you click on that link the modal will close and the cookie is set to "true"
    // path "/" means it's active for the entire root site.. if you set it to "/admin" will be active on the "admin" folder
    // expires in 7 days
    // "modal" is the name i gave the cookie.. you can name it anything you want
    $('#modal_close').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.cookie("modal", "true", { path: '/', expires: 7 });


    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 3):

You will have to call the S.prettyPhoto.open API function after the page is done loading. I put it under the $(document).ready(function() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'fast',slideshow:10000});
            $(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'fast',slideshow:10000});

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:260px; height:265px"></div>',
                changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
            });

            $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:last").prettyPhoto({
                custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_1237859" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_1251710" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div>',
                //changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }

            });
            $.prettyPhoto.open('FMWM5.swf?width=544 &amp;height=399', '', 'Click anywhere to skip intro...');
            setTimeout("$.prettyPhoto.close()", 8000);

        });
```

changepicturecallback was giving me a "_bsap is not defined" error (seen in firebug) so i commented it out.

Here's the scrap page I was using for testing: 
http://www.fortmitchellwalmart.com/prettyPhotoTest/index.html

I don't know how to disable it with the cookie boolean, I'm pretty much a noob with javascripting and flash, but hope this helps!